# How can I determine that Y_n can be represented as a funtion of X_n

Tags: r, matlab, math

On enter I'm having a sequence of pairs `(X_n, Y_n)`. Consider the following two graphics of two possible sequences.

[image]

[image]

in first case `X_n` can be modeled as `f(Y_n)` while in second case it obviously has no sense. The question is how can I determine if trying to represent `X_n` as `f(Y_n)` makes sense? Probable there is some criterium or something like that?

What can be done in multivariate situation (i.e. when we're trying to represent `Y` as `f(X_1, X_2, ..., X_k)`)?

Please note that trying to fit points with something graphicaly (e.g. like on first graph) and seeing if it fits the data is not OK. I'm looking for numerical criterium.

Please feel free to propose variants in either matlab or R. A link on page with algorithm will be great too!

Comment: Least squares fitting is well understood.  You can judge goodness of fit using R^2 and SSE.  Why isn't that sufficient?

Comment: This is just an idea: Compute the concave hull and somehow determine whether it is thin enough.

Comment: Maybe [fit a polynomial](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) of some maximum degree and see how it looks.

Comment: Using @duffymo and Luis ideas, decide on a maximum degree of polynomial. Fit and based on a least mean square (LMS) criteria judge if that is an acceptable fit and thus "makes sense".

Comment: [Goodness of Fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit). This questions is leaning more towards mathematics than programming and thus might be off-topic for SO.

Comment: Unless you have different *y* values for exactly the same *x* value, there is *always* a whole lot of functions which exactly represents *y* as a function of *x*, e.g. using polynomial interpolation. Most of them will be far from what you'd expect from looking at the points, though. So be sure you formulate your requirements accordingly.